# Are Bifenthrin granules safe to use outside when I have cats inside?

Tags: cats, ticks

I am in the deep woods and ticks are bad this year. Seems like they are getting worse over time.

I have a 3 foot wide gravel trail down to the house. The trail is about 100 feet long. Intent is to use Bifenthrin 0.05% granules on either side of the trail and around the house as a barrier, excluding anywhere I walk - there is a rock trail around the house too.

I should generally not be tracking the granules inside, will not apply to the gravel.

I am going to get a handheld spreader, likely a battery powered one and spread the granules.

Is using Bifenthrin this way safe as I have cats inside? They do not go outside.

My current read is that this is safe.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifenthrin

https://www.ortho.com/en-us/products/bugs/ortho-home-defense-insect-killer-granules3

Thanks!

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/249552/are-bifenthrin-granules-safe-to-use-outside-when-i-have-cats-inside

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! May you have some kind of list of ingredients of this treatment?

Comment: Do you know, that ticks usually sit in grass and bushes waiting for animals/persons passing? So there should be none on a simple road... And also "securing the trail" would not change anything

Comment: it is safe for your cat and for other mamals but killing all insects-snails and fish that might come in contact with the neuro toxin might be taking it a bit too far in my opinion.

Comment: Allerleirauh - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifenthrin  Yes, I know they are on the blades of grass.  Please know, I am in the deep woods in the cold north east and clearly this problem is getting worse (perhaps as the climate gets warmer).  I have had two on me this year so far - definitely from high blades of grass.  I have trimmed either side of the trail and the area behind the shed where I picked up the 2nd tick.  The property is literally infested with deer - This is a constant problem.  So I want to do all I can do to prevent another problem.  Additional trimming to be done.

Comment: trond - please see comment above.  No, I am not happy about spraying, but here, its like a hornets nest inside the house - its a safety issue for me, I do not want to get a tick bite - I am also clearly inside the lyme disease zone.

Comment: I am hoping I can come to an understanding that spraying or spreading granules on the sides of the trail *outside* is ok - as long as I don't track it in. Bifen IS toxic to cats, specifically, but not do dogs or humans.  Cats livers cant process it, but that's for direct application as if it was a permethrin spot-on for dogs, don't do that on a cat.

Comment: Until you got a solution: wear the trousers inside the socks when outside, change clothes when coming inside, shower and have a close look to skin areas damp and with blood directly under the skin (behind ears, neck, intim area, behind knees, under the shoulders...). Ticks wander around for 2 to 5 hours on the skin before they bite.

Comment: @HouseDiY If you add an "@" before the name, the person will get a notice that there is a comment waiting :)